# TransactionScope EF Net Core RollBack in foreach cycle complete

Tags: entity-framework, asynchronous, .net-core, http-get, transactionscope

these are my two functions to import records in my DB, roolback is not performed and I purposely make a fault to test it. My idea when the call to http or the content fails, complete classroom are imported, that is, each cycle of the Foreach

```
public async Task SeedAllAsync()
{
    List<ClassRoom> classrooms = new List<ClassRoom> 
    {
        DataStore.ClassRooms.GetById("Class1")),
        DataStore.ClassRooms.GetById("Class2")),
        DataStore.ClassRooms.GetById("Class3"))
    };
    foreach (ClassRoom c in classrooms) 
    {               
        using (TransactionScope txscope = 
                new TransactionScope(   TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, 
                                        TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
        {
            try 
            {                                       
                Task task = SeedStudents(c);
                await task;        
                txscope.Complete();                        
            }
            catch (MyAppError p) {
                Console.WriteLine("LOG MyAppError : " + p.Message);                        
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine("LOG Exception : " + e.Message);                        
            }
        }
    }
}


private async Task SeedStudents(ClassRoom cr)
{   
    List<Student> listStudents = await CallerHttpAsync.GetStudents(cr.id); 
    foreach (Student est in listStudents) 
    {
        //***********************************************************
        //All Classrooms have 10 Students
        if (cr.id == 2 && est.Name.Contains("Adam"))
            throw new MyAppError("Error purposely caused for the second loop and the student Adam");
        //Adam would be the fifth student 
        //***********************************************************
        cr.Add(student);                
    }
    Ds.SaveChanges();
}
```

I have tried everything, Database.BeginTransaction (), EnlistTransaction, Database.AutoTransactionsEnabled = false, put the TransactionScope inside SeedStudents and also in and out at the same time.

**UPDATE** : Really what I think happens is that the commit of the third cycle saves the changes that were half of the second cycle. Attached bud not saved.

Please suppose something is wrong

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE** : Example 
1) foreach import correctly "Class1"
2) Loop import "Class2" have a error (no import bud remain in context)
3) When loop import "Class3" de student's of class2 are imported (there is my problem)

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are trying to achieve and what the problem is.  Can you edit the question to make it more clear?

Comment: **UPDATE** I have a process that performs import actions and repeats several times through a foreach.

What I need is that every time a cycle is executed it is complete. In other words, if an error occurs in the cycle, the movements will not be inserted (correct) but as they remain in the context, the next cycle of the loop inserts them.That's what you do not want.


I do not know if I explain better now